# Why do we say "plant a kiss"?

Tags: meaning, nouns, metaphors

The term [plant](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plant) means a living organism; a thing with roots, shoots and leaves that needs water and sun in order to grow.  So why do we say "to plant a kiss"?

> She planted a kiss...

[image]

Comment: Because you're hoping something will sprout.

Comment: (Hint:  Look at the **verb** definition in that link you posted.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb comes to us circuitously from the Latin [*plantare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dplanto), which had the same two related senses that we use, the one agricultural and the other meaning to fix in place.  In the latter case, we plant ourselves into a position to fight, we plant spies in the enemy's camp, and we plant kisses on the cheeks of our beloveds.

Comment: Another driveby downvote, a curse upon this site.

Answer (score 2):

*To plant* suggests the idea of placing something in the ground (possibly with affection and or dedication) for future growth. The metaphor used for a kiss coneys the idea of a vigorous kiss, one that you are likely to remember.

From the OED

***Plant a kiss:***

> - spec. to place (a kiss) on the lips, cheek, etc., usu. with gusto or deliberation.
>
>   - ***1906*** Galsworthy Man of Property i. ix. 122 Moved by some inexplicable desire to assert his proprietorship, he rose from his chair and planted a kiss on his wife's shoulder.
>   - ***1937*** G. Frankau More of Us xii. 125 Was this The ruleress of waves, R.N., all-British, Who stooped to plant the Cytherean Kiss?

Comment: Plussed because you conveyed the special senses of 'to plant a kiss': vigor, gusto, deliberation.

Answer (score 0):

To plant something means you hope it will grow or spread in future. So plant a kiss here means a person thinks kissing should grow and spread to more people and that person is starting on that mission by kissing one or more people.

Comment: This is whimsical, but wrong. See Hot Licks' second comment; the first was a joke.